# Simply select char, or string

Tags: postgresql, squirrel-sql

What is the way to achieve expected result from psql select:

```
SELECT 'Hello world';
```

using this in SQuirreL I get value:  in unnamed column. What is the way to get string *Hello world* as a result?

I want to use this approach to format outputs using commas, colons, etc. Is there another way to pre-prepare results for further usage?

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: What do you mean by *...to get string Hello world as a result...*? You want it to be a column name or something else? Apart from that use RDBMS to process and fetch necessary data and client code to format and present that data.

Comment: I want get one column with 'Hello word' as its content. Column name is  unset here (in squirrel '?column?')

Answer (score 1):

> *I want get one column with 'Hello word' as its content. Column name is unset here (in squirrel '?column?')*

It's because you didn't give that column a name (alias)

If you'll do it like this

```
SELECT 'Hello world' AS column_name
```

you'll get

```
| COLUMN_NAME |
|-------------|
| Hello world |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/d41d8/1318)** demo

Comment: Thaks, column name change works but its not an issue, column data is still '<Other>' in my case. I use psql 8.4. I'm not able to get SQLFiddle working with psql 8.4.(it writes something about connection error).

Comment: Here is working [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!10/d41d8/132) with postgres 8.3. Try another client if squirrel is giving you this.

Comment: You are right it works, it is some SQuirreL issue, using psql client I get the same as on SQLFiddle. Thaks

Comment: You're quite welcome :) If you feel like the answer was helpful please, consider to **[accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)** it.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I ran into the same problem with SQuirreL, and found a simple work-around.  Try this in SQuirreL:

```
SELECT trim('Hello world') AS column_name;
```

Actually, any of the PostgreSQL string functions will work, like upper(), lower(), etc., depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear but I give you the possible optionsin one block

begin
    declare @PreDefinedVariable nvarchar(50)
    Select @PreDefinedVariable = 'Hello World!'
    select @PreDefinedVariable as [Result]
end

Answer (score 0):

It is an SQuirreL SQL Client issue, using psql from bash I get expected:

```
tdb14=> SELECT 'Hello world' AS column_name;
 column_name 
-------------
 Hello world
(1 row)
```